# How to display and hide a tooltip message on mouseenter and mouseleave respectively?

Tags: angular, d3.js

I want to display some message on mouseenter and hide that message on mouseleave. Although the mouseenter event is working fine, the mouseleave event is not working. The tooltip message stays even when the pointer is removed. How can it be fixed?

```
    .on("mouseenter", function(d: PieArcDatum<BandMembers>) {
         let xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
         let yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
         d3.select(this);

         tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
         tooltip.select("text").text(d.data.Members) 
})
    .on("mouseleave", function(d: PieArcDatum<BandMembers>) {
         d3.select(this)
         tooltip.style("display", null); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.style("display", "none")`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this `tooltip.style("display", null);` to `tooltip.style("display", none);`, which will add style like `display: none` for the mouse leave event